# How to sign Apache server so all requests originating from a directory are via HTTPS and contain your Private Key?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, ssl, x509certificate

So I got accepted into the [MintChip Challenge](http://developer.mintchipchallenge.com/), but unfortunately I don't have a supported mobile device (Android, iPhone or Windows Phone), so I'll have to use the [Hosted API](http://developer.mintchipchallenge.com/api/hosted/index.php). I'm planning to use JavaScript/PHP for interacting with the API. The only problem is that when I try to request data, I get a [403 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_status_codes#403) meaning the API understood my request but chose to reject it.

I do know that all requests require SSL and [signing with your provided certificate](http://blog.codekills.net/2012/04/07/a-first-look-at-mintchip%27s-hosted-api%27s-crypto/). I also know my certificates are valid and [imported to my browser](http://www.onlinehowto.net/install-ssl-certificate-in-firefox/784) correctly, because I can get into the Hosted API and see requests directly, by hitting any of the URLs, i.e.:
https://remote.mintchipchallenge.com/mintchip/info/json

So the big question is, **can Apache Web Server itself be signed for all requests** the same way my browser can be, to enable server-server signed requests. Short of that, does PHP have any library or utilities for importing an x.509 certificate and signing your request with it?

I'd usually use JSONp to do a client-server request to a JSON API, which would get around this need, but understandably JSONp was seen as a security risk and thus not supported by MintChip. I also can't think of any other API that requires this level of security for every request, usually just BASIC Auth or ws-security or something, is this overkill and does it even make things more secure? General info questions are not usually looked at favorably as I already have a warning on this question before even posting but maybe some Security professionals have more info on how to sign Apache Web Server, force SSL for all requests from a particular directory, protect keys while storing them on the server, using x.509 via PHP, etc? Thanks for your help.

(UPDATED: 2012-05-04, change title to reflect the fact that you sign requests with your private key, and they would of course be decrypted with your public key)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use a PHP application as a client for another server, using client-certificate authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Apache server does not generate API requests to MintChip itself, so there is no way to make it start signing requests that it doesn't know about.

It is, in all likelihood, not appropriate to be creating requests to the MintChip API directly through a client web browser. There is no good way you could guarantee that the client have certificates in place anyway.

If you are making API requests through PHP using the [curl](http://php.net/curl) extension, you can use the `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` option when making a request to specify a client certificate to use. Ideally, you should have all your code which performs an API request in a single location (e.g, a `mintchip_api` function), so there should be no need to make this apply to "all requests originating from a directory".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better security-wise to force all communication to the app to happen over HTTPS though? Facebook does this as well when you set your privacy settings to the highest level, but that of course may be overkill and I know some users complained about it.

Comment: Yes, communication between the web application and the client browser should probably be using HTTPS as well. HOWEVER, that should be entirely separate from communications between your web application and MintChip -- the client has no business talking to MintChip directly. Same as how your browser isn't involved directly in credit card transactions when making an online purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you sign with private keys...  not with public keys as an X.509 cert would contain.

As for using X.509 through PHP...  check out [phpseclib, a pure PHP X.509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net).